# "The general principles of the constitution are with us the result of judicial decisions"

Tags: legalese

"are with us" just sounds wrong. Is it? I'm not familiar 1885 English.

Anne Dennett. [*Public Law Directions* (1 ed 2019)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Public-Law-Directions-Anne-Dennett/dp/0198807317). p. 149.

> Dicey set out his principles on the rule of law in 1885 (*Introduction to the Study of Law and
>   Constitution*) and they are still relevant today. Dicey suggested three views of the rule of
>   law based on the supremacy of law and the idea that no man is above the law (‘Englishmen
>   are ruled by the law, and by the law alone’). It is useful to know in advance that Dicey did
>   not trust wide governmental power.

I skip here.

> 3. ‘[T]he general principles of the constitution (as for example the right to personal liberty,
>      or the right of public meeting) **are with us** the result of judicial decisions determining
>      the rights of private persons in particular cases brought before the Courts; whereas
>      under many foreign constitutions the security (such as it is) given to the rights of individuals
>      results, or appears to result, from the general principles of the constitution.’
>
> In the UK, rights and freedoms are the result of the common law, not a written constitution
>   or code of rights; therefore the UK’s unwritten constitution is the result of the ordinary law
>   of the land and is ‘pervaded by the rule of law’. (While this was true at the time that Dicey
>   was writing, rights and freedoms are now also protected by statutes such as the Equality
>   Act 2010 and Human Rights Act 1998.)

Comment: Just guessing -- maybe it means the principles are, with us, the result of etc.

Comment: @aparente001 - more likely it means the principles are with us **as** the result of ...

Comment: '...) which exist in the UK have arisen in the UK as _the result of_ ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I don't understand.

Comment: [T]he general principles of the constitution (as for example the right to personal liberty, or the right of public meeting) [are with us the result of] / [which exist in the UK have arisen in the UK as the result of]  judicial decisions determining the rights of private persons in particular cases brought before the Courts

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - got it.  Thank you.  You expanded on what Aml wrote (with us as the result of etc.).  I hope one of you will write an answer.

Comment: @AmI - pinging you too.

Comment: @aparente001 - and 'with us' indicates a mild form of possession: "are with us" = "are ours" ("[as] the result of" = "because of").

Comment: @AmI - Are you ready to write an answer?

Comment: @AmI - Was that written in code? // Anyway, suit yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the 19th c. *with* where contemporary speakers are more likely to use a different preposition, such as *for* or *among*, was fairly common.

> [*With us*](https://books.google.de/books?id=tZQOFOwQ0fcC&pg=PP46&dq=%22with+us%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir26za7LfnAhVN_aQKHQOcCwM4HhDoATAJegQIARBI) it [a type of mint] is rather rare; growing in waste ground, generally where there is moisture; and flowering in August and September. — *English Botany; Or, Coloured Figures of British Plants*,  1802.
>
> Nevertheless, let truth be ever sacred [*with us*](https://books.google.de/books?id=A-02AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA319&dq=%22with+us%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIraGR7LfnAhWXwAIHHYWPCn84ChDoATABegQIARAL) ; for God sees and abhors all deceit. — Job Orton, Robert Gentleman, *A short and plain exposition of the Old Testament*, 1805.
>
> Among the Turks, a beard is a mark of dignity; [*with us*](https://books.google.de/books?id=DddgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP191&dq=%22with+us%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYzZq377fnAhXF5KQKHcuqAbI4PBDoATABegQIARAJ#v=onepage&q=%22with%20us%22&f=false), of negligence. Shaving the head is, *with them*, a custom; *with us*, a punishment … *With us*, the women parade in gay colours, and the men in sombre ; *with them*, in both cases, it is the reverse.  — *A Handbook for Travellers in the Ionian Islands, Greece, Turkey, ...*, 1840.

While this usage seems antiquated to us, I can think of one context where it doesn’t sound out of date:

> But Gregory and Justin—the boys, as we call them—that's not the case [*with them*](https://faeryinkpress.com/books/gear-and-sea). When they have an idea, they see it through. — Gear & Sea | Faery Ink Press, 4 Oct. 2019.
>
> I think that was the way it was [*with my father*](https://books.google.de/books?id=npt_CQAAQBAJ&pg=PT160&dq=%22the+way+it+was+with%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrvNfc-LfnAhXhN-wKHag4DFYQ6AEILDAB). He cleaned offices and he never thought about being owner of that company.  — Vida 'Sister' Goldman Prince,  — *That's the Way it Was*, 2013.